# Example of a separated variety which is not quasi-projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, separation-axioms

I am following Kempf's book on algebraic varieties. A variety there is defined to be a space with functions having a finite affine open cover.

Call a variety $X$ separated if its diagonal $$\mathrm{diag} (X)=\{ (x,x)\mid x\in X\}$$ is closed in $X\times X$. In Lemma 3.3.2, Kempf proves that quasi-projective varieties are separated. My question is: does there exist an example of a separated variety which is non-quasi-projective?

PS: This is my first time posting a question here. Please feel free to suggest ways to make it better.

Comment: For those of us who don't have Kempf's book on hand it might be helpful if you define a variety - there are a lot of definitions floating around. Indeed one definition is "integral, separated of finite type over a field" which would make your requirement of "separated" to be rather pointless - and one could simply take the famous counterexample of Nagata to break the quasi-projectiveness.

Comment: One small tip: please don't use math mode to format non-math text. I've fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are many examples of proper (thus separated) varieties which are not projective and therefore not quasi-projective. Here's a list of some examples:

- [Hironaka's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example).
- [Nagata's existence theorem for nonprojective complete varieties](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-2/issue-4A/Existence-theorems-for-nonprojective-complete-algebraic-varieties/10.1215/ijm/1255454111.full) associates to every function field of dimension 2 or more a complete nonprojective variety (some conditions on the base field are necessary in dimension 2).
- Hartshorne exercise II.7.13: Let $C=V(y^2z=x^3+x^2z)\subset\Bbb P^2_k$ be the nodal cubic for $k$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic not 2, which has smooth locus isomorphic to $\Bbb G_m$. Glue $C\times(\Bbb P^2\setminus \{0\})$ and $C\times(\Bbb P^2\setminus \{\infty\})$ along $C\times(\Bbb P^2\setminus \{0,\infty\})$ by the automorphism given by sending $(p,u)\mapsto (up,u)$. This has zero picard group and therefore cannot be projective.
- Hartshorne exercise III.5.9 produces an infinitesimal extension of $\Bbb P^2_k$ over a field of characteristic zero which isn't projective.
- [Do complete nonprojective varieties arise "in nature"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111504/do-complete-non-projective-varieties-arise-in-nature) on MO contains more discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer and tip! Should I give the post some time before accepting your answer?

Comment: It's up to you - one can accept, unaccept, or change which answer is accepted at any time. You may find [this discussion about accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) helpful.

Comment: "[...] varieties which are not projective and therefore not quasi-projective": does the punctured affine plane not provide an example of a quasi-projective variety which is not projective?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Perhaps I should clarify: if a proper variety is quasi-projective, then it is projective. So a proper variety which is not projective cannot be quasi-projective. Thus to answer your question about quasi-projectivity it suffices to talk about projectivity when dealing with proper varieties (all of the examples are of this form).